# Анимация и постепенная загрузка SVG изображений

Tags: jquery, css, css3, svg, css-animation

Как  реализовать анимацию рисования линии при помощи `stroke-dasharray` до нужного значения?

Я пробовал transition, animate jquery, но нужного эффекта  не добился, плавности увеличения синего круга нет. И еще нужно сделать, чтобы окружности рисовались друг за другом. Я пробовал реализовать это за счет уменьшения времени анимации каждой последующей окружности в 2 раза, но тогда анимацию сделать уже нельзя, так как пока дойдет очередь до нужного элемента, его анимация уже отыграла. 
 https://codepen.io/donchak1610/pen/OjLopQ?editors=1010

```
div.circle-wrap
 svg(class = 'circle')
  circle(transform='rotate(-90)' r='50' cx='-60' cy='60')
  circle(id='skill-html' class='circle-svg' transform='rotate(-90)' 
 style='stroke-dasharray:220px 314px;' r='50' cx='-60' cy='60')
```

Comment: Я вопрос не понял.

Comment: Qwertiy, при загрузке страницы svg постепенно загружаются друг за другом, при загрузке происходит анимация загрузки в круге

Comment: A, ясно. Надо использовать animation, а не transition, если элементы создаются динамически.

Comment: @Qwertiy я пробовал animation, но свойство stroke-dasharray оно не анимирует

Comment: Потому что анимировать надо dashoffset.

Answer (score 5):

Плавное рисование окружности с нуля до заданного значения можно реализовать с помощью изменения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` - это отступ от начала рисования линии.

При максимальном значении отступа равного длине окружности - линия не видна.

При нулевом значении `stroke-dashoffset="0"` - линия будет прорисована полностью.
Длина окружности при радиусе `r=50px` равна `2*3.14*50 = 314px`

Как я понял из вашего примера, вам нужно прорисовать линию с нуля до `3/4` окружности, поэтому `stroke-dashoffset` будет уменьшаться от максимума - `314px` до `78.5px` (одна четвертая часть окружности будет не заполнена)

### Вариант анимации CSS

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" >

<style>
.cr1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 314;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 78.5;
  }
}

</style> 
 <g stroke-width="20">
   <circle class="bg1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5" />   
 <circle class="cr1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Начальной точкой рисования линии для окружности является положительная ось `"X"`

Для изменения положения начальной точки вверху, необходимо повернуть окружность

на `-90` градусов. `transform="rotate(-90 100 100)"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" >

<style>
.cr1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 314;
  stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  animation: dash 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 314;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 78.5;
  }
}

</style> 
 <g stroke-width="20" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)">
   <circle class="bg1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5" />   
 <circle class="cr1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue" />
</g>
</svg>
```

### Вариант анимации SVG

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
 <g stroke-width="20" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)">
   <circle class="bg1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5"  />   
 <circle class="cr1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke-dasharray="314" stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue">
 <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0" values="314;78.5" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>  
 </g>

</svg>
```

### Последовательная анимация нескольких окружностей

Код не сильно отличается от примера выше с одной окружностью. 
Добавлены уникальные идентификаторы анимации для каждой окружности  : `an1`, `an2`, `an3`. 
Начало анимации заполнения второй окружности начинается  после окончания первой анимации - `begin="an1.end"` Начало анимации для третьей окружности - `begin="an2.end"`

```
<animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an1.end" values="314;78.5" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 600 600">


 <g stroke-width="20">
   <circle class="bg1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5"  />   
 <circle class="cr1" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke-dasharray="314" stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue">
 <animate id="an1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0" values="314;78.5" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>  

 <circle class="bg2" cx="250" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5"  />   
 <circle class="cr2" cx="250" cy="100" r="50" stroke-dasharray="314" stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" stroke=" yellowgreen">
 <animate id="an2" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an1.end" values="314;78.5" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>  
 
 <circle class="bg3" cx="400" cy="100" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#dfdcd5"  />   
 <circle class="cr3" cx="400" cy="100" r="50" stroke-dasharray="314" stroke-dashoffset="314" fill="none" stroke=" mediumvioletred">
 <animate id="an3" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an2.end" values="314;78.5" dur="2s" fill="freeze" />
 </circle>
  
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: @Дмитрий Моисеев Если ответ вам был полезен, отметьте его галочкой напротив цифры –