# Комплексная анимация персонажа гитхаба

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation

У меня есть решение, как сделать анимацию персонажа гитхаба с помощью CSS.
Но возможно, есть более интересные решения, чем изменять прозрачность картинки, применять фильтры.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже мой код.

```css
img:not(:hover) {
  transition: 2s;
  filter: saturate(0%);
  -webkit-filter: saturate(0%);
   opacity:0.2;
  }
img:hover {
  transition: 1s;
 
}
```

```html
 <div>
  <img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1GPx.png"  width="300px" height="300px" alt="github"/>
  </div>
```

Необходимо реализовать более комплексную анимацию с отрисовкой деталей частей картинки, анимацией закраски.
 Я понимаю, что наверное, с помощью чистого CSS это не представляется возможным. Необходимо в дополнении использовать SVG.
Принимаются любые варианты. Отдам **решение** за хорошие идеи и реализацию.

Answer (score 5):

**Вариант анимации SVG**

Нашел на бесплатных векторных стоках это изображение в формате SVG. Строго говоря это не лого гитхаба, а изображение похожее на него.
Моя цель не изменять его, не менять цвета, не использовать его в коммерческих целях, а сделать комплексную анимацию, которая будет состоять из нескольких этапов: прорисовка с нуля контуров изображения, заполнение их цветом в последовательных и параллельных режимах.

Для реализации анимации определяются части кода, которые отвечают за отдельные части изображения. Им присваиваются уникальные идентификаторы. Например для патча рисующего тело кота - `id="body"` Для анимации рисования линии туловища  `id="strBody"`, для анимации заполнения цветом туловища кота - `id="fillBody"`

**Анимация рисования туловища с нуля и заполнение его цветом**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 256 259.3" >
<svg>
<path id="body" fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#010101" stroke-dasharray="1533" stroke-dashoffset="1533" d="M255.8 95.6l0.2-0.9c-21.1-4.2-42.7-4.3-55.8-3.7 2.1-7.7 2.8-16.7 2.8-26.6 0-14.3-5.4-25.7-14-34.3 1.5-4.9 3.5-15.8-2-29.7 0 0-9.8-3.1-32.1 11.8 -8.7-2.2-18-3.3-27.3-3.3 -10.2 0-20.5 1.3-30.2 3.9C74.4-2.9 64.3 0.3 64.3 0.3c-6.6 16.5-2.5 28.8-1.3 31.8 -7.8 8.4-12.5 19.1-12.5 32.2 0 9.9 1.1 18.8 3.9 26.5 -13.2-0.5-34-0.3-54.4 3.8l0.2 0.9c20.4-4.1 41.4-4.2 54.5-3.7 0.6 1.6 1.3 3.2 2 4.7 -13 0.4-35.1 2.1-56.3 8.1l0.3 0.9c21.4-6 43.7-7.6 56.6-8 7.8 14.4 23 23.8 50.2 26.7 -3.9 2.6-7.8 7-9.4 14.5 -5.3 2.5-21.9 8.7-31.9-8.5 0 0-5.6-10.2-16.3-11 0 0-10.4-0.2-0.7 6.5 0 0 6.9 3.3 11.7 15.6 0 0 6.3 21 36.4 14.2V177c0 0-0.6 7.7-7.7 10.2 0 0-4.2 2.9 0.3 4.5 0 0 19.5 1.6 19.5-14.4v-23.6c0 0-0.8-9.4 3.8-12.6v38.8c0 0-0.3 9.3-5.1 12.8 0 0-3.2 5.7 3.8 4.2 0 0 13.4-1.9 14-17.6l0.3-39.3h3.2l0.3 39.3c0.6 15.6 14 17.6 14 17.6 7 1.6 3.8-4.2 3.8-4.2 -4.8-3.5-5.1-12.8-5.1-12.8v-38.5c4.6 3.6 3.8 12.3 3.8 12.3v23.6c0 16 19.5 14.4 19.5 14.4 4.5-1.6 0.3-4.5 0.3-4.5 -7-2.6-7.7-10.2-7.7-10.2v-31c0-12.1-5.1-18.5-10.1-21.8 29-2.9 42.9-12.2 49.3-26.8 12.7 0.3 35.6 1.9 57.4 8.1l0.3-0.9c-21.7-6.1-44.4-7.7-57.3-8.1 0.6-1.5 1.1-3 1.6-4.6C212.9 91.4 234.6 91.4 255.8 95.6L255.8 95.6zM255.8 95.6">
 <animate id="strBody"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="1533;0" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
  <animate id="fillBody"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#010101"  dur="5s" fill="freeze" />  
 </path> 
 </svg>
```

Для анимации рисования линии используется уменьшение значения атрибута `stroke-dashoffset` (отступ от начала линии) c максимального значения `1533px` до нуля.

```
<animate id="strBody"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="1533;0" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
```

Анимация заполнением цветом начинается после окончания рисования линии

```
<animate id="fillBody"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#010101"  dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
```

И так повторяется для каждой части изображения.

Для параллельного запуска нескольких анимациий, например прорисовка глаз кошки, ставится одинаковое условие запуска, - окончание одной и той же анимации

```
<animate id="fillLeftEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />    
<animate id="fillRightEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
```

**Полный вариант анимации персонажа**

```html
<doctype! html>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="256" height="259" viewBox="0 0 256 259.3" >
  <g  style="opacity:0;">
  <path fill="#9EDCF2" opacity="1" d="M200.9 199.8c0 13.9-32.2 25.1-71.9 25.1 -39.7 0-71.9-11.3-71.9-25.1 0-13.9 32.2-25.1 71.9-25.1C168.7 174.7 200.9 185.9 200.9 199.8L200.9 199.8zM200.9 199.8">
  
  </path>
  <defs>
    
 <path id="shade_of_paws" d="M98.1 244.8c1.6 7.5 5.5 11.9 9.4 14.5l41.1 0c5-3.4 10.1-9.8 10.1-21.8v-31c0 0 0.6-7.7 7.7-10.2 0 0 4.1-2.9-0.3-4.5 0 0-19.5-1.6-19.5 14.4v23.6c0 0 0.8 8.7-3.8 12.3v-29.2c0 0 0.3-9.3 5.1-12.8 0 0 3.2-5.7-3.8-4.2 0 0-13.4 1.9-14 17.6l-0.3 30h-3.2l-0.3-30c-0.6-15.6-14-17.6-14-17.6 -7-1.6-3.8 4.2-3.8 4.2 4.8 3.5 5.1 12.8 5.1 12.8v29.5c-4.6-3.3-3.8-12.6-3.8-12.6v-23.6c0-16-19.5-14.4-19.5-14.4 -4.5 1.6-0.3 4.5-0.3 4.5 7 2.6 7.7 10.2 7.7 10.2v21.7L98.1 244.8z"/>
  </defs>
  <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
    <use xlink:href="#shade_of_paws" overflow="visible"/>
  </clipPath>
  <path clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#7DBCE7" d="M200.9 199.8c0 13.9-32.2 25.1-71.9 25.1 -39.7 0-71.9-11.3-71.9-25.1 0-13.9 32.2-25.1 71.9-25.1C168.7 174.7 200.9 185.9 200.9 199.8L200.9 199.8zM200.9 199.8"/>
 <animate attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="fillBody.end-3s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" /> 
 </g>
  
  
  <path id="body" fill="none" opacity="1" stroke="#010101" stroke-dasharray="1533" stroke-dashoffset="1533" d="M255.8 95.6l0.2-0.9c-21.1-4.2-42.7-4.3-55.8-3.7 2.1-7.7 2.8-16.7 2.8-26.6 0-14.3-5.4-25.7-14-34.3 1.5-4.9 3.5-15.8-2-29.7 0 0-9.8-3.1-32.1 11.8 -8.7-2.2-18-3.3-27.3-3.3 -10.2 0-20.5 1.3-30.2 3.9C74.4-2.9 64.3 0.3 64.3 0.3c-6.6 16.5-2.5 28.8-1.3 31.8 -7.8 8.4-12.5 19.1-12.5 32.2 0 9.9 1.1 18.8 3.9 26.5 -13.2-0.5-34-0.3-54.4 3.8l0.2 0.9c20.4-4.1 41.4-4.2 54.5-3.7 0.6 1.6 1.3 3.2 2 4.7 -13 0.4-35.1 2.1-56.3 8.1l0.3 0.9c21.4-6 43.7-7.6 56.6-8 7.8 14.4 23 23.8 50.2 26.7 -3.9 2.6-7.8 7-9.4 14.5 -5.3 2.5-21.9 8.7-31.9-8.5 0 0-5.6-10.2-16.3-11 0 0-10.4-0.2-0.7 6.5 0 0 6.9 3.3 11.7 15.6 0 0 6.3 21 36.4 14.2V177c0 0-0.6 7.7-7.7 10.2 0 0-4.2 2.9 0.3 4.5 0 0 19.5 1.6 19.5-14.4v-23.6c0 0-0.8-9.4 3.8-12.6v38.8c0 0-0.3 9.3-5.1 12.8 0 0-3.2 5.7 3.8 4.2 0 0 13.4-1.9 14-17.6l0.3-39.3h3.2l0.3 39.3c0.6 15.6 14 17.6 14 17.6 7 1.6 3.8-4.2 3.8-4.2 -4.8-3.5-5.1-12.8-5.1-12.8v-38.5c4.6 3.6 3.8 12.3 3.8 12.3v23.6c0 16 19.5 14.4 19.5 14.4 4.5-1.6 0.3-4.5 0.3-4.5 -7-2.6-7.7-10.2-7.7-10.2v-31c0-12.1-5.1-18.5-10.1-21.8 29-2.9 42.9-12.2 49.3-26.8 12.7 0.3 35.6 1.9 57.4 8.1l0.3-0.9c-21.7-6.1-44.4-7.7-57.3-8.1 0.6-1.5 1.1-3 1.6-4.6C212.9 91.4 234.6 91.4 255.8 95.6L255.8 95.6zM255.8 95.6">
 <animate id="strBody"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="1533;0" dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" /> 
  <animate id="fillBody"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillMuzzle.end" values="#fff;#010101"  dur="5s" fill="freeze" />  
 </path>
 
 
  
  <path id="muzzle" fill="none" stroke="#F5CCB3" stroke-dasharray="298" stroke-dashoffset="298" d="M174.6 63.7c6.2 5.7 9.9 12.5 9.9 19.8 0 34.4-25.6 35.3-57.2 35.3 -31.6 0-57.2-4.8-57.2-35.3 0-7.3 3.6-14.1 9.8-19.7 10.3-9.4 27.7-4.4 47.4-4.4C147 59.4 164.3 54.3 174.6 63.7L174.6 63.7zM174.6 63.7">
  <animate id="strMuzzle"  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="strBody.end" values="298;0" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" /> 
  <animate id="fillMuzzle"  attributeName="fill" begin="strMuzzle.end" values="#fff;#F5CCB3"  dur="0.25s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
 
 
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M108.3 85.3c0 9.5-5.3 17.1-11.9 17.1 -6.6 0-11.9-7.7-11.9-17.1 0-9.5 5.3-17.1 11.9-17.1C103 68.1 108.3 75.8 108.3 85.3L108.3 85.3zM108.3 85.3"/>
 
 <path  id="leftEye"fill="#fff" d="M104.5 85.5c0 6.3-3.6 11.4-7.9 11.4 -4.4 0-7.9-5.1-7.9-11.4 0-6.3 3.6-11.4 7.9-11.4C100.9 74.1 104.5 79.2 104.5 85.5L104.5 85.5zM104.5 85.5">
 <animate id="fillLeftEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
 </path>

 <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M172.2 85.3c0 9.5-5.3 17.1-11.9 17.1 -6.6 0-11.9-7.7-11.9-17.1 0-9.5 5.3-17.1 11.9-17.1C166.8 68.1 172.2 75.8 172.2 85.3L172.2 85.3zM172.2 85.3"/>
 
  <path  id="rightEye" fill="#fff" d="M168.3 85.5c0 6.3-3.6 11.4-7.9 11.4 -4.4 0-7.9-5.1-7.9-11.4 0-6.3 3.6-11.4 7.9-11.4C164.8 74.1 168.3 79.2 168.3 85.5L168.3 85.5zM168.3 85.5">
  <animate id="fillRightEye"  attributeName="fill" begin="strBody.end" values="#fff;#AF5C51"  dur="1.5s" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
  
  <path id="nose" fill="#fff" d="M130.5 100.5c0 1.6-1.3 3-3 3 -1.6 0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3 3-3C129.1 97.5 130.5 98.8 130.5 100.5L130.5 100.5zM130.5 100.5">
  <animate id="fillNose"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillRightEye.end+0.5s" values="#fff;#F5CCB3;#AF5C51"  dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
 </path>
  <path id="Mouth" fill="#fff" d="M120.6 108c-0.2-0.5 0.1-1 0.6-1.2 0.5-0.2 1 0.1 1.2 0.6 0.8 2.2 2.8 3.6 5.1 3.6 2.3 0 4.3-1.5 5.1-3.6 0.2-0.5 0.7-0.8 1.2-0.6 0.5 0.2 0.8 0.7 0.6 1.2 -1 2.9-3.8 4.9-6.9 4.9C124.4 112.9 121.6 110.9 120.6 108L120.6 108zM120.6 108">
  <animate id="fillMouth"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillNose.end" values="#fff;#F5CCB3;#AF5C51"  dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path id="Dash1" fill="#fff" d="M54.5 121.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C53.6 120.2 54.5 120.8 54.5 121.6L54.5 121.6zM54.5 121.6">
  <animate id="fillDash1"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillBody.end-3s" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  <path id="Dash2" fill="#fff" d="M60.3 124.8c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C59.4 123.4 60.3 124 60.3 124.8L60.3 124.8zM60.3 124.8">
  <animate id="fillDash2"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash1.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path id="Dash3" fill="#fff" d="M63.8 129c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C62.9 127.5 63.8 128.2 63.8 129L63.8 129zM63.8 129">
   <animate id="fillDash3"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash2.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path id="Dash4" fill="#fff" d="M67 133.8c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C66.1 132.3 67 133 67 133.8L67 133.8zM67 133.8">
  <animate id="fillDash4"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash3.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  
  <path id="Dash5" fill="#fff" d="M70.5 138.2c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C69.6 136.8 70.5 137.4 70.5 138.2L70.5 138.2zM70.5 138.2">
   <animate id="fillDash5"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash4.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
  
  <path id="Dash6" fill="#fff" d="M75.3 142.1c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C74.4 140.6 75.3 141.3 75.3 142.1L75.3 142.1zM75.3 142.1">
     <animate id="fillDash6"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash5.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
  
  <path id="Dash7" fill="#fff" d="M82 144.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C81.1 143.2 82 143.8 82 144.6L82 144.6zM82 144.6">
   <animate id="fillDash7"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash6.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
 
 <path id="Dash8" fill="#fff" d="M88.7 144.6c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C87.8 143.2 88.7 143.8 88.7 144.6L88.7 144.6zM88.7 144.6"> 
    <animate id="fillDash8"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash7.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
 
 
  <path id="Dash9" fill="#fff" d="M95.5 143.5c0 0.8-0.9 1.4-2.1 1.4 -1.1 0-2.1-0.6-2.1-1.4 0-0.8 0.9-1.4 2.1-1.4C94.5 142.1 95.5 142.7 95.5 143.5L95.5 143.5zM95.5 143.5"> 
      <animate id="fillDash9"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash8.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
  
  <path id="droplet" fill="#fff" d="M46.9 125.9l-2.1 7.2c0 0-0.5 2.6 1.9 3.1 2.6-0.1 2.4-2.5 2.2-3.2L46.9 125.9 46.9 125.9zM46.9 125.9">  
  
   <animate id="fillDash10"  attributeName="fill" begin="fillDash9.end" values="#fff;#C4E5D9"  dur="0.2s" fill="freeze" />
  </path> 
  
</svg>
```

Эта техника использования уникальных идентификаторов для выстраивания последовательности запуска анимаций очень полезна. Не нужно высчитывать тайминг окончания, начала, согласование по   времени. В любой момент можно легко поменять порядок запуска анимаций.

**Примеры с использованием этой техники**

[Совместная анимация схемы и иконок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723733/28748)
[Последовательная анимация нескольких окружностей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/697951/28748)
[Плавный морфинг одного изображения в другое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/686831/28748)

Answer (score 0):

#### [GitHub Logos and Usage](https://github.com/logos)

#### Please don’t do these things

1. Use the Octocat or GitHub logo for your application’s icon
2. Create a modified version of the Octocat or GitHub logo
3. Integrate the Octocat or GitHub logo into your logo
4. Use any GitHub artwork without permission
5. Sell any GitHub artwork without permission
6. Change the colors, dimensions or add your own text/images

Comment: Последний пункт как-то не очень строго соблюдается: [тысячи их](https://octodex.github.com/).