# Совместить clip-path и box-shadow

Tags: css, css3, svg

Господа, есть блок, который обрезан с помощью  clip-path, но при этом  box-shadow игнорируется... Как можно решить данную проблему?  В итоге, надо данному блоку, приведенному в примере задать тень?

```css
.logo {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px #00000099;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

P.S. Если clip-path закоментировать,  box-shadow работает

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Самое простая реализация тени, как  предложил в комментариях `splash58`(см. переход по ссылке) использовать два одинаковых контура. Нижний контур сдвигается вправо и вниз и выступает в роли тени. 
То же самое, но намного проще можно сделать посредством svg.

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <polygon id="Shadow" fill="grey" transform="translate(4 4)" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke-width="2" fill="grey"/>
  <polygon id="Logo" fill="dodgerblue" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Настраиваете по своему вкусу отступы и цвет тени  `transform="translate(4 4)"` и `fill="grey"`

### Вариант с размытием тени

Для размытия тени применен фильтр гаусса

```html
<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <defs>
    <filter id="Filtershadow" height="120%" width="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="4"/> 
    </filter>
  </defs>  
  <polygon id="Shadow" fill="grey" transform="translate(4 4)" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="none" stroke-width="2" fill="grey" filter="url(#Filtershadow)"/>
  <polygon id="Logo" fill="grey" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="none" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

### Решение CSS

Немного доработан пример по ссылке  `splash58`

```css
#box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3CF;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}

#shadow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: второй вариант лучше

Comment: @Air тут три варианта :-) Какой второй? Второй svg с размытием тени или вариант CSS?

Comment: ага)))))))))))))))))

Comment: Это только у меня на втором варианте тень обрезана по краям? Выглядит так-то не очень. Полагаю если нужно размытие то нужен только CSS вариант.

Comment: @Telion не обрезана тень, а размыта фильтром. У каждого свой вкус. Поэтому я написал в ответе, что можете регулировать, степень размытия, отступы, цвет тени. В svg всё это достаточно просто

Comment: Нееет, она то размыта, а размытие обрезается, это видно довольно четко на всех углах. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/d06ia1eyhfretc1/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80.png?dl=0)

Comment: @Telion молодец! Пригляделся и понял, что ты имеешь ввиду. Упустил из виду, что фильтр по умолчанию имеет диапазон действия 120%, а остальное подрезает, у меня не хватило пространства, чтобы фильтр отрисовался полностью. Подредактировал атрибуты вот так выглядит сейчас подложка, которая обеспечивает тень https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzXfJ.png

Comment: @Alexandr_T, уже сделал))  по этому коммент убрал... я думал ты не читал еще)) благодарю

Comment: @Air не жадничай :-) покажи людям, как сделал прямо здесь

Comment: @Alexandr_T, ок закончу напишу. Но ответом глупо писать. А коменте реализовать, как то не комильфо ...

Answer (score 4):

**Добавление тени к растровой картинке средствами svg**

Вопрос появился в комментариях, я счёл, что ответ на него будет полезен и оформляю отдельным ответом. Тем более, что тут будет несколько иная техника реализации.

- Для обрезания изображения используется маска. Для придания формы
  маске используется полигон.

  `<mask id="poly">
   <polygon id="Logo" fill="white" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" 
     stroke="none" /> 
  </mask>`

Чтобы маска стала прозрачной она закрашивается в белый цвет `fill="white"`
 Для полупрозрачной маски  `fill="grey"`,  полностью непрозрачно - `fill="black"`

- Для тени применяется тот же полигон со смещением, и  размытием краев
  фильтром Гаусса.

  `<filter id="filtershadow" width="120%" height="120%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
  </filter>`

ниже полный код:

```html
<svg width="125" height="125" viewBox="0 0 125 125" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="filtershadow" width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
    </filter>   
    <mask id="poly">
      <polygon id="Logo" fill="white" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="none" stroke-width="1"/> 
    </mask> 
  </defs>
  <g id="pic"> 
    <polygon id="Logo" transform="translate(4 4)" fill="black" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" filter="url(#filtershadow)"/> 
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
 xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any"
 mask="url(#poly)"/>
  </g> 
</svg>
```

**Несколько изображений с тенью**

Применяется приём повторного использования с командой `<use>`

Блок отвечающий за отрисовку изображения и размытой тени обертывается тегом группы `<g id="pic">..</g>`, а затем повторно используется с указанием смещения объекта клона:

`<use xlink:href="#pic" x="20" y="20"> </use>`

```html
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filtershadow" width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
    </filter>   
    <mask id="poly">
      <polygon id="Logo" fill="white" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"/> 
    </mask> 
  </defs>
  <g id="pic"> 
    <polygon id="Logo" transform="translate(4 4)" fill="black" points="0 0, 100 0, 100 83, 70 100, 0 100" stroke="grey" stroke-width="2" filter="url(#filtershadow)"/> 
    <image x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="http://placeimg.com/100/100/any"
 mask="url(#poly)"/>
  </g>  
  <use xlink:href="#pic" x="20" y="20"/>
  <use xlink:href="#pic" x="40" y="40"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Супер))))))!!!!!

Comment: @Air  благодарю Мне оч. близок слоган в ваше профиле  "ДЕЛАЕШЬ ДЛЯ ДРУГИХ, УЧИШЬ ДЛЯ СЕБЯ"...  :-) Непонятно другое, почему действительно интересные работы остаются без должного внимания https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/734919/28748

Comment: я кстати этот вопрос из ссылки добавил себе в избранные, но о твоем ответе не получал уведомление...

Answer (score 4):

Надо обернуть лого в ещё один div и применить тень к нему. Также подозреваю, что стоит `box-shadow` заменить на `filter: drop-shadow(...)`:

```css
.logo {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background: gray;
  margin-left: 10px;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 83%, 70% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.wrapper {
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 15px #00000099);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это же svg... Вообще из головы вылетело...  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 15px #00000099); Хорошая идея...

Comment: Так в коде в вопросе нет svg. Зачем городить svg, если просто css хватает?

Comment: Не в коде вопроса... Но `clip-path` IE  не поддерживает....  Вот про `svg`  я и думал...

Comment: Кстати, что у тя с вопросом `Получить пересечение двух путей` разобрался?

Comment: Ничего, забил пока.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, этот вопрос уже не актуален для автора, но думаю такие новички как я наткнутся когда-то на него, и так как для себя я здесь ответа не нашёл, пошёл искать на других ресурсах и нашёл ответ на css.tricks. Вот ссылка на ответ
https://css-tricks.com/using-box-shadows-and-clip-path-together/

Решение, как по мне, очень простое. Когда мы используем clip-path, то не можем использовать тень, так как она будет обрезана. Но мы можем откинуть тень от родителя нашого элемента. Но если мы просто добавим ему тень, то она будет иметь форму родителя, для того же чтобы форма тени была такой же, как и того элемента которому она нужна, мы можем использовать даную строку:
filter: drop-shadow() с нужными нам параметрами.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Извините, но автор вопроса принял один из ответов, то есть, он ему помог. Не могли бы вы уточнить, почему вам не помог?

Comment: Можно узнать, чем описанное решение отличается от [моего ответа под этим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/830416/178988)?

Comment: @0xdb, у принятого ответа есть сложности с применимостью к обычному html. А вот чем описанное отличается от моего ответа, я не понимаю.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хотел побудить автора обосновать это голословное утверждение - _я здесь ответа не нашёл_, не важно какого ответа, он пишет о всех. Ответа повидимому не дождаться. Ну раз ещё и дублирует ранее  данный ответ, то может просто удалим?

Comment: @0xdb, ну почему ж не дождаться, он же ответ дополнил после первого комментария. Может просто по выходным на сайт не заходит? С моей стороны удалять конкурирующие ответы не совсем правильно ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, можно подождать. На наши комментарии он ещё получит уведомления, заострим внимание, так сказать.

Comment: @Qwertie должен извенится перед вами, искал ответ ночью, был уставший и не увидел вашего ответа. Ваш комментарий полностью о том же что и ваш, но как по мне, на css.tricks там более детально описано почему и как работает данное решение.

Comment: @0xdb по выходным действительно не захожу 